# Issues with Kubernetes multi-master using kubeadm on premises

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, high-availability

Following Kubernetes v1.11 [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/), I have managed to setup Kubernetes high availability using kubeadm, stacked control plane nodes, with 3 masters running on-premises on CentOS7 VMs. But with no load-balancer available, I used Keepalived to set a failover virtual IP (10.171.4.12) for apiserver as described in Kubernetes v1.10 [documentation](https://v1-10.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#set-up-master-load-balancer). As a result, my "kubeadm-config.yaml" used to boostrap the control planes had the following header:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha2  
kind: MasterConfiguration  
kubernetesVersion: v1.11.0  
apiServerCertSANs:  
- "10.171.4.12"  
api:  
    controlPlaneEndpoint: "10.171.4.12:6443"  
etcd:  
  ...
```

The configuration went fine with the following Warning that appeared when boostrapping all 3 Masters:

> *[endpoint] WARNING: port specified in api.controlPlaneEndpoint
>   overrides api.bindPort in the controlplane address*

And this Warning when joining Workers:

> [WARNING RequiredIPVSKernelModulesAvailable]: the IPVS proxier will
>   not be used, because the following required kernel modules are not
>   loaded: [ip_vs ip_vs_rr ip_vs_wrr ip_vs_sh] or no builtin kernel ipvs
>   support: map[ip_vs:{} ip_vs_rr:{} ip_vs_wrr:{} ip_vs_sh:{}
>   nf_conntrack_ipv4:{}] you can solve this problem with following
>   methods:
>    1. Run 'modprobe -- ' to load missing kernel modules;
>    2. Provide the missing builtin kernel ipvs support

## Afterwards, basic tests succeed:

- When stopped, Keepalived is failing over to another Master and apiserver is always accessible (all kubectl commands succeed).
- When stopping the main Master (with highest Keepalived preference), the deployment of apps is successful (tested with Kubernetes bootcamp) and everything syncs properly with the main Master when it is back online.
- Kubernetes bootcamp application runs successfully, and all master & worker nodes respond properly when the service exposing bootcamp with NodePort is curled.
- Successfully deployed docker-registry as per https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/docker-registry

## But then comes these issues:

- Nginx Ingress Controller pod fails to run and enters state CrashLoopBackOff (refer to events below)
- After installing helm and tiller on any Master, all commands using "helm install" or "helm list" failed to execute (refer to command ouputs below)

I am running Kubernetes v1.11.1 but kubeadm-config.yaml mentions 1.11.0, is this something I should worry about?

Shall I not follow the official documentation and go for other alternatives such as described at: https://medium.com/@bambash/ha-kubernetes-cluster-via-kubeadm-b2133360b198

Note: same issue with new Kubernetes HA installation using the latest version 1.11.2 (three masters + one worker) and deployed nginx latest ingress controller release 0.18.0.

## -- Nginx controller pod events & logs:

```
  Normal   Pulled     28m (x38 over 2h)  kubelet, node3.local  Container image "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.17.1" already present on machine  
  Warning  Unhealthy  7m (x137 over 2h)  kubelet, node3.local  Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.240.3.14:10254/healthz: dial tcp 10.240.3.14:10254: connect: connection refused  
  Warning  BackOff    2m (x502 over 2h)  kubelet, node3.local  Back-off restarting failed container  

nginx version: nginx/1.13.12  
W0809 14:05:46.171066       5 client_config.go:552] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.  
I0809 14:05:46.171748       5 main.go:191] Creating API client for https://10.250.0.1:443
```

## -- helm command outputs:

```
'# helm install ...  
Error: no available release name found

'# helm list  
Error: Get https://10.250.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%!D(MISSING)TILLER: dial tcp 10.250.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

## -- kubernetes service & endpoints:

```
# kubectl describe svc kubernetes
Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
                   provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.250.0.1
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        6443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.171.4.10:6443,10.171.4.8:6443,10.171.4.9:6443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>


# kubectl get endpoints --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                      ENDPOINTS                                               AGE
default         bc-svc                    10.240.3.27:8080                                        6d
default         kubernetes                10.171.4.10:6443,10.171.4.8:6443,10.171.4.9:6443        7d
ingress-nginx   default-http-backend      10.240.3.24:8080                                        4d
kube-system     kube-controller-manager   <none>                                                  7d
kube-system     kube-dns                  10.240.2.4:53,10.240.2.5:53,10.240.2.4:53 + 1 more...   7d
kube-system     kube-scheduler            <none>                                                  7d
kube-system     tiller-deploy             10.240.3.25:44134                                       5d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems solved when switched my POD network from Flanneld to Calico.
(tested on Kubernetes 1.11.0; will repeat tests tomorrow on latest k8s version 1.11.2)

Comment: Tests successful with k8s versions 1.11.1 and 1.11.2

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Kubernetes client-go code](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/bdfc4cfc125f556bfe46fff68207767a605b64ed/rest/config.go#L313:6), IP address and port are read from environment variables inside a container:

```
host, port := os.Getenv("KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST"), os.Getenv("KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT")
```

You can check these variables if you run following command mentioning any healthy pod in it:

```
$ kubectl exec <healthy-pod-name> -- printenv | grep SERVICE
```

I think the cause of the problem is that the variables `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT` is set to `10.250.0.1:443` instead of `10.171.4.12:6443`

Could you confirm it by checking these variables in your cluster?

Comment: Confirmed, I am getting 10.250.0.1:443 instead of 10.171.4.12:6443, as per the below extract:  # kubectl exec kubernetes-bootcamp-69bf88c8c-7h527 -- printenv | grep SERVICE                                  KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443  
BC_SVC_SERVICE_HOST=10.250.203.134  
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.250.0.1  
BC_SVC_SERVICE_PORT=8080  
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443  
BC_SVC_SERVICE_PORT_PORT_1=8080

Comment: Hello, today I performed a new Kubernetes HA installation using the latest version 1.11.2 (three masters + one worker) and deployed [nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/deploy) latest ingress controller release 0.18.0 but still facing the same problems reported above, and the variables KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST and KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT are set to the Kubernetes service private IP. Is this considered as a bug in the latest K8s release? or can it be solved with a simple workaround?

Comment: I have checked the same env variable from a healthy pod on a Kubernetes environment with single Master and healthy Nginx Ingress Controller and Helm, and variables KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST and KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT are always set to the Kubernetes service private IP and port 443; So I think this is not the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Could you add to your question output of two following commands: <kubectl describe svc kubernetes> and <kubectl get endpoints --all-namespaces>

Comment: As suggested, I have added the commands output to the initial question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Important Additional Notes:

After running couple of labs, I got the same issue with:
- new Kubernetes HA installation using the latest version 1.11.2 (three masters + one worker) and nginx latest ingress controller release 0.18.0.
- standalone Kubernetes master with few workers using version 1.11.1 (one master + two workers) and nginx latest ingress controller release 0.18.0.
- but with standalone Kubernetes master version 1.11.0 (one master + two workers), nginx ingress controller 0.17.1 worked with no complaints while 0.18.0 complained that Readiness probe failed but the pod went into the running state.

=> As a result, I think the issue is related to kubernetes releases 1.11.1 and 1.11.2 in the way they interpret the health probes maybe